# Append some text to the end of multiple files in Linux

Tags: file, bash, unix

How can I append the following code to the end of numerous php files in a directory and its sub directory:

```
</div>
<div id="preloader" style="display:none;position: absolute;top: 90px;margin-left: 265px;">
<img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>
```

I have tried with:

```
echo "my text" >> *.php
```

But the terminal displays the error:

```
bash : *.php: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't specify the shell, you could try the `foreach` command. Under tcsh (and I'm sure a very similar version is available for bash) you can say something like interactively:

```
foreach i (*.php)
foreach> echo "my text" >> $i
foreach> end
```

`$i` will take on the name of each file each time through the loop.

As always, when doing operations on a large number of files, it's probably a good idea to test them in a small directory with sample files to make sure it works as expected.

Oops .. `bash` in error message (I'll tag your question with it). The equivalent loop would be

```
for i in *.php
do 
   echo "my text" >> $i
done
```

If you want to cover multiple directories below the one where you are you can specify

```
*/*.php
```

rather than `*.php`

Comment: What about the files in the sub directories? I need to append on it as well.
PS: I used the command
`for i in $a
do
echo "the code" >> $i
done`
But in all files it appended twice and nothing happened to the files in the sub directories.

Comment: For the bash example quote `$i` to handle files with spaces in them for

Answer (score 127):

I usually use tee because I think it looks a little cleaner and it generally fits on one line.

```
echo "my text" | tee -a *.php
```

Comment: This is a Dantastic answer. :-)  And since the OP is using bash, setting globstar will also allow it to handle PHP files in subdirectories.

Comment: what if i need to append a string to multiple specific files. I have multiple wordpress installs, and I need to add a string to the end of every file called functions.php. would this be possible with tee?

Comment: Very nice, this also supports globstar e.g
`echo "my text" | tee -a **/*.php` if needed :)

Answer (score 23):

[BashFAQ/056](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/056) does a decent job of explaining why what you tried doesn't work.  Have a look.

Since you're using bash (according to your error), the `for` command is your friend.

```
for filename in *.php; do
  echo "text" >> "$filename"
done
```

If you'd like to pull "text" from a file, you could instead do this:

```
for filename in *.php; do
  cat /path/to/sourcefile >> "$filename"
done
```

Now ... you *might* have files in subdirectories.  If so, you could use the `find` command to find and process them:

```
find . -name "*.php" -type f -exec sh -c "cat /path/to/sourcefile >> {}" \;
```

The `find` command identifies what files using conditions like `-name` and `-type`, then the `-exec` command runs basically the same thing I showed you in the previous "for" loop.  The final `\;` indicates to `find` that this is the end of arguments to the `-exec` option.

You can `man find` for lots more details about this.

The `find` command is portable and is generally recommended for this kind of activity especially if you want your solution to be portable to other systems.  But since you're currently using `bash`, you may also be able to handle subdirectories using bash's `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
for filename in **/*.php; do
  cat /path/to/sourcefile >> "$filename"
done
```

You can `man bash` and search for "globstar" for more details about this. This option requires bash version 4 or higher.

**NOTE**: You may have other problems with what you're doing.  PHP scripts don't **need** to end with a `?>`, so you might be adding HTML that the script will try to interpret as PHP code.

Comment: It did nothing. Returned no error but did not append any lines in any file as well.

Comment: I've updated the command with something that should be a bit more flexible.  If you show us your *actual* command line, we may be able to debug.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sed`  combined with `find`. Assume your project tree is

```
    /MyProject/ 
    /MyProject/Page1/file.php
    /MyProject/Page2/file.php
    etc.
```

1. Save the code you want to append on `/MyProject/`. Call it `append.txt`
2. From  `/MyProject/` run:

   ```
   find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i '$r append.txt'
   ```

   Explain:

   - `find` does as it is, it looks for all .php, including subdirectories
   - `xargs` will pass (i.e. run) `sed` for all .php that have just been found
   - `sed` will do the appending. '$r append.txt' means go to the end of the file ($) and write (paste) whatever is in append.txt there. Don't forget `-i` otherwise it will just print out the appended file and not save it.

Source: http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Sed.html#uh-37

Answer (score 3):

You can do (Work even if there's space in your file path) :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a tempory file named /tmp/end_of_my_php.txt
cat << EOF > /tmp/end_of_my_php.txt
</div>
<div id="preloader" style="display:none;position: absolute;top: 90px;margin-left: 265px;">
<img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>
</div>
EOF

find . -type f -name "*.php" | while read the_file
do
    echo "Processing $the_file"
    #cp "$the_file" "${the_file}.bak" # Uncomment if you want to save a backup of your file
    cat /tmp/end_of_my_php.txt >> "$the_file"
done

echo
echo done
```

PS: You must run the script from the directory you want to browse

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from @Dantastic answer :

```
echo "my text" | tee -a file1.txt | tee -a file2.txt
```

Comment: To avoid displaying anything in the terminal (e.g. when used in a script): 
`echo "my text" | tee -a file1.txt | tee -a file2.txt >/dev/null`

Comment: you can simply: `echo "my text" | tee -a file1.txt file2.txt`. No need to pipe to a second tee.